# Style PHP echo output(s) differently

Tags: php, html, css

Currently trying to style this php code so the outputs are displayed differently. For example, if i wanted `"Posts<br>"` to be gray and `$user['num_posts']` to be yellow:

```
 <a href="" class="commposts">
        <?php echo "Posts<br>" . $user['num_posts'];?>
 </a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make use of two individual elements (such as `<span>`) and give them unique classes or IDS which you can then style. In the following, `.posts` contains the string `Posts` and will be red, while `.num-posts` contains `$user['num_posts']` and will be yellow.

```
<a href="" class="commposts">
    <?php echo "<span class='posts'>Posts</span>" . "<span class='num-posts'>" . $user['num_posts'] . "</span>"; ?>
</a>

.posts {
  color: red;
}

.num-posts {
  color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare CSS classes that specify the colors you want:

```
.yellow {
    color: yellow;
}
.gray {
    color: gray;
}
```

Then wrap spans with these classes around the appropriate parts of the output.

```
<a href="" class="commposts">
    <span class='grey'>Posts</span><br><span class='yellow'><?php echo $user['num_posts'];?></span>
</a>
```

Also, just put `<?php echo` around the variable parts of the output, not around the whole line.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the only thing in that that needs to be in php is the actual value of the posts number - i would do it as follows: - note the display block on the span - it prevents the need for a html `<br>` element - its always best to use CSS for the layout - not HMTL.

```
<a href="" class="commposts">
    Posts <span> <?php echo $user['num_posts'];?> </span>
 </a>

Then the styling is

.commposts {color: gray}
.commposts span {color: yellow; display: block;}
```

To see this in action (obviously without the php)

```css
.commposts {
  color: gray;
  text-decoration: none;
 }
 
.commposts span {
  color: red;
  display: block;
 }
```

```html
<a href="" class="commposts">
    Posts <span>3</span>
 </a>
```